# How can i request image locations through elements api for an entry in section?

Tags: json, plugin-elementapi

i have endpoint: 
`'news/<slug:{slug}>.json'`
i print out EntryModel-Class in transformer function and it doesn´t seem to contain any photos like how it is described in [Element Api](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) example loop at the bottom of docs.
i need to return all images and their locations as json for specific entry.
any ideas?

```
'news/<slug:{slug}>.json' => function($slug) {

        return [

            'criteria' => [
                'section' => 'news',
                'slug' => $slug

            ],
            'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {


                print_r($entry);

                //doesnt work --->
                // $photos = [];
                // foreach ($entry->photos as $photo) {
                //     $photos[] = $photo->url;
                // }
                //<----- doesnt work

                return [
                    'locale' => $entry->locale,
                    'slug' => $entry->slug,
                    'status' => $entry->status,
                    'title' => $entry->title,
                    'url' => $entry->url,
                    'uri' => $entry->uri,

                    'id' => $entry->id,
                    'heading' => $entry->heading,
                    'subheading' => $entry->subheading,

                    'linkUrl' => $entry->linkUrl,
                    'postDate' => $entry->postDate,

                    'children' => $entry->children,
                    'author' => $entry->author,
                    'link' => $entry->link,
                    'next' => $entry->next,
                    'parent' => $entry->parent,
                    'section' => $entry->section,
                    'type' => $entry->type,
                    'ancestors' => $entry->ancestors,
                    'body' => $entry->body,
                    'articleBody' => $entry->articleBody,
                    'featuredImage' => $entry->featuredImage,
                    'backgroundColor' => $entry->backgroundColor,
                    'serviceBody' => $entry->serviceBody,
                    'featuredThumb'=>$entry->featuredThumb,
                    'heroImage'=>$entry->heroImage,
                    'indexHeading'=>$entry->indexHeading,
                    'shortDescription'=>$entry->shortDescription,
                    'root'=>$entry->root
                    // 'photos' => $photos    <- i need image locations related to an entry
                    //'fields' => $entry->fields
                    // 'caption' => $entry->caption
                    // 'shortDescription'=> $entry->shortDescription,
                    // 'elementId' => $entry->elementId,


                ];
            },


        ];
    }
```

nothing under postDate seems to return anything....